# How spipu html2pdf to support variety of languages

Tags: php, tcpdf, html2pdf

I have a project to use spipu/html2pdf package to generate pdf documents, this pdf need to support all variety of languages

I am trying to use freeserif font as default font, the freeserif font support most western languages, including Hindi and Arabic. But seems not support Japanese/Korea/Chinese. Does anyone know which font under TCPDF support all
all variety of languages? or how to can support all variety of languages using spipu/html2pdf package. Thanks.

Here is my test code:

```
$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr', true, "UTF-8");
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('freeserif');
$content = nl2br($PageTag);
$html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
```

Comment: Take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14027/24599 for some ideas